# Geonodes: bezier curve displacement, but I want the start of the bezier curve to stay at the origin point and gradually displaces? (fall-off like)

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, displacement

I have a bezier curve and I've added some noise displacements via offsetting the position with a noise texture in geonode. But I need the start point of the bezier curve to remain at the origin of the curve and not to be displaced.

[image: set up 1]

[image: set up 2]

The second picture is kind of like what I want to do. But rather than abruptly turning and connecting to the starting point, I would like it to be a smoother transition, kind of like a fall-off or easing? like gradually returning to the start point.

Comment: I know it doesn't matter much because the second image is not really the solution you wanted... but instead of using the _Endpoint Selection_ with a _Start Size_ of 499 and an _End Size_ of 0, you could have set it to _Start Size_ 0 and _End Size_ 1 and then afterwards put a _Boolean Math_ node set to _Not_. This way it would always exclude the last point, no matter which value you set as _Count_ in the _Resample Curve_ node.

Comment: Thank you! this will definitely help me in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

So after a few experimenting, I think I've found the solution, at least it works for my case. I'm still quite new to geo-nodes so better solutions are always welcomed!